# Solr4 installation with Jetty

Tags: linux, solr, jetty

I am trying to install Solr4 latest and want to run it with Jetty (servlet container).

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre
JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dsolr.solr.home=/opt/solr $JAVA_OPTIONS"
JETTY_HOME=/opt/solr
JETTY_USER=solr
JETTY_LOGS=/opt/solr/logs
JETTY_ARGS=/opt/solr/etc/jetty-plus.xml
```

I download jetty init script from **[LINK](http://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/rt/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty/trunk/jetty-distribution/src/main/resources/bin/jetty.sh)**

I added it chkconfig. Issue which I facing is that when I start jetty it is not getting started.  I followed the instructions provided on **[URL](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrJetty)** but nothing seems to be working.

netstat output

```
[root@localhost ~]# netstat -tlnp | grep 8983
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Nothing comes up in log file too I checked syslog as well as log defined in jetty too.

However when i run **service jetty supervise** it works and I can see the jetty is listening on port 8080. But its not getting started with init script.

Any clue what I have missed here, or let me know if any more infor is required from my end.

**Aditional Info**

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_65"

cat /etc/issue
Amazon Linux AMI release 2014.03
Kernel \r on an \m

Solr 4.10 
jetty-distribution-9.2.3.v20140905
```

**EDITED**

```
set -x 
/etc/init.d/jetty restart
+ /etc/init.d/jetty restart
Stopping Jetty: OK
Starting Jetty: STARTED Jetty Thu Sep 18 18:07:27 UTC 2014
++ printf '\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007' root localhost '~'
```

Comment: Can you add at init script start the following `set -x` and post the output ?

Comment: I have provided the URL for init script which I am using its given by solr I will add the set -x output now

Comment: @Pierre-Yves Gillier :I have updated as you asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing to bash shell should work for you. It seems that you have messed with installation

Let me give you steps to do it which worked for me:

I downloaded [solr4.10.1](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/lucene/solr/4.10.1) .

```
cd /tmp
wget http://apache.arvixe.com/lucene/solr/4.10.1/solr-4.10.1.tgz
tar -xzf solr-4.10.1.tgz
```

As you have messed up the installation I would suggest to take backup if you want and delete `/opt/solr` and do the following

```
cp -rf /tmp/solr-4.10.1/example /opt/solr
```

Adduser solr if not added

```
useradd -d /opt/solr -s /sbin/false solr
chown solr:solr -R /opt/solr
```

> From Apache [link](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrJetty)
>
> **NOTE:** If you don't have start-stop-daemon tool you have to setup /bin/bash instead /sbin/false.

Create default jetty file as below :

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre
JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dsolr.solr.home=/opt/solr/solr $JAVA_OPTIONS"
JETTY_HOME=/opt/solr
JETTY_USER=solr
JETTY_LOGS=/opt/solr/logs
```

**NOTE:** If you notice `JAVA_OPTIONS` in your default jetty file I have changed it to `/opt/solr/solr` do the same. Let other thing remain same.

Create `/opt/solr/etc/jetty-logging.xml` as Provided on [link](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrJetty)

Now download `jetty 7` init script

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eclipse/jetty.project/master/jetty-distribution/src/main/resources/bin/jetty.sh

cp jetty.sh /etc/init.d/jetty
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/jetty
chkconfig jetty on
```

So far we did single Solr installation with single core (collection1) , now start solr service and check if it is running and listening on default port

```
service jetty start
```

Go to your URL and `http://IP:8983/solr` and it should work fine for you.

Now we will go for `Multicore` setup

Move the folder `/opt/solr/solr` to `/opt/solr/solr-bkp` or delete it .

```
mv /opt/solr/solr /opt/solr/solr-bkp
```

Move the `multicore` folder as  `/opt/solr/solr`

```
mv /opt/solr/multicore /opt/solr/solr
```

And you are done other details you can follow from the document  [SolrJetty](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrJetty)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for detailed steps .. Let me try this as well and will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've resolved this, but having gone through the same trouble, the fix for me was setting the shell for the solr user to /bin/bash instead of /bin/false.

Comment: No that did not work for me :( `grep solr /etc/passwd
solr:x:501:502::/opt/solr:/bin/bash`